# Get Querystring value using c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, query-string

I am using the below code to assign the iframe src through javascript.It's working fine. But in c# code behind i got the query string like this. `id=Y&amp%3bcust_id=100&amp%3`. How can i reduce this.Now

```
var value = "validity.aspx?id=Y&cust_id=" + cust_id + "";
frameElement.src = value
```

i want to get the value of customer from query string but it always return null.

```
if(Request.QueryString["cust_id"] !=null) //It returns null
```

Comment: place a breakpoint at the var value line and see what does cust_id have in it

Comment: it returns null.But it holds exact customer id.Due to this reason it returns null.

Comment: Server.UrlDecode(xxxxxxxx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode your "&" caracters.  For some reason, the server is reading them as &amp%3b.

Try this:

```
var value = "validity.aspx?id=Y&cust_id=" + cust_id + "";
value = encodeURIComponent(value);
frameElement.src = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the URL using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode

Try something like this:

```
var value = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(URL);
```

Comment: hey bro, do you delete your question? sql-substract-row-wise-value-from-previous-row-value-cumulative... cannot find the page anymore